# Can not verify JWT token of Azure AD with openid scope in java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, jwt, digital-signature, verify

I am developing a Backend code for a company to log in to our application in Login with Azure Ad User. I have to be able to make a JWT Verify.

I read too many posts. I'm trying to use the AUTH0 library. I have tried a lot, but still "com.auth Where do I make mistakes?

```
       try {
            String token = "your-token-here"; // set real token
            String tenant_id = "your-tenant_id"; // set tenant id
            String jwkSetUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id + "/discovery/v2.0/keys";
            DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(token);
            JwkProvider jwkProvider = null;

            jwkProvider = new UrlJwkProvider(new URL(jwkSetUri));

            Jwk jwk = jwkProvider.get(decodedJWT.getKeyId());
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256((RSAPublicKey) jwk.getPublicKey(), null);
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                    .withIssuer("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id + "/v2.0")
                    .build();
            DecodedJWT verifiedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
            // do something with the verified JWT
            System.out.println("Jwt is valid: " + verifiedJWT);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvalidPublicKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (JwkException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: SHA256withRSA
    at com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.RSAAlgorithm.verify(RSAAlgorithm.java:51)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:463)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:445)
    at com.wheelme.client.App.main(App.java:31)
```

Mobile app gets token, then send a request to backend. some information I have outside of token is like that:

```
{ "issuer": ["sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXX/"], // one of // 'iss' claim 
"tenant": "XXXXXXXXXX", // 'tid' claim 
"client": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // 'appid' claim "audience": 
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // 'aud' claim 
"scope": "openid" // 'scp' claim contains array of the whitespace-separated scopes }
```

Mobile uses this to get token:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#prefer-the-auth-code-flow

How can I fix this code?

Comment: How are you acquiring the token? What scope(s) are you using? Note that if it is an MS Graph API token, you won't be able to validate it. Make sure you use a scope defined in your app registration under Expose an API.

Comment: Mobile app gets token, then send a request to backend. some information is like that:
{
  "issuer": ["https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXX/"], // one of // 'iss' claim
  "tenant": "XXXXXXXXXX", // 'tid' claim
  "client": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // 'appid' claim
  "audience": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", // 'aud' claim
  "scope": "openid" // 'scp' claim contains array of the whitespace-separated scopes
}

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#prefer-the-auth-code-flow
mobile app uses this

Comment: Are the scopes like openid or User.Read or are they scopes that you have defined in Expose an API page?

Comment: scope is openid and flow is like that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#prefer-the-auth-code-flow

Comment: That's the ID token then. You need an access token.

Comment: I have an access token,  I am trying to verify the bearer token.  I tried to share other information, not the token.

Comment: Or hmm, maybe I did in fact say that wrong. If the scope is openid, it is not correct for your API anyway. You need to use a scope you defined in your app registration when acquiring the access token.

Comment: Can't I write my own JWT parse and verify method for a token created with scope openid?